# Dunlop valve with schrader chuck compatibility

Tags: tire, valves

I have a dunlop (or woods) valve that I would like to inflate.
I am trying to avoid needing to screw on a chuck, so I was looking at some options online to be able to do this, but most chucks that allow this capability are schrader chucks.
So would a schrader chuck work with a dunlop valve?

Answer (score 3):

Many track pumps have universal heads. There are mainly two types of such heads:

- two openings:

  - One for Dunlop (aka Woods, Blitz, English) and Presta (Sclaverand, French), that simply pushes a narrow
    rubber grommet over the valve.
  - One opening for Schrader (Auto, American) valve that also has a mechanism to depresses the valve core and has
    an internal valve. An internal mechanism closes the air supply to
    whichever hole is open (no pressure).

[image: Topeak twin head][image: BBB head]

- a single opening with a rubber grommet that is constricted on the valve stem of any valve by closing a lever at the back of the head. This lever also pushes down a rod in the head that opens the valve core of Schrader valves. For other valves this mechanism is pushed aside when the head is pushed onto the valve.

[image: SKS EVA head]

Such pump heads can be bought as spare parts without a track pump. Often they are compatible with hoses of other pump brands. For example, I replaced the head on my Park Tool pump with an universal 'EVA' head from SKS for 5 EUR.

Answer (score 1):

No sadly, dunlop/woods is not compatible with schrader/AV.

However, it is completely compatible with presta valves in terms of thread and diameter.  Your dunlop valve should work fine with a presta-capable pump, although there is a risk of interference from parts of the nozzle.

Your other option is to get a cheap Presta-to-Schrader adapter and use the schrader pump.

Answer (score 0):

Schrader and Dunlop valve stems have the same diametre. That means that inner tubes with either valve fit equally well into rims. You might simply replace the inner tube with a valve you like better.

This does not apply to Presta valves. They are much narrower. You can identify Presta valves by having a little nut that has to be unscrewed to open the valve core.

I've done it the other way round. We had a children's bike with Schrader valves where I put in Dunlop (actually 'Blitz' valves) to make it easier to pump for children. Our track pump has a universal pump head. It is much easier to pump Dunlop and Presta than Schrader where the valve core has to be opened by the pump head.